# How to remove multiple occurrence of char and leave only one

Tags: c

I'm not able to figure out how to replace multiple char inputs in a single one as shown above. The sample input contains an array of elements which take a char and int as a combination.

And output **is to be sorted** and multiple occurrence is to be removed and replaced with a single one, moreover the integer related to char should be added.

Sample Input:

```
5
M 25
A 50
O 70
A 45
L 100
```

Sample Output:

```
A 95
L 100
M 25
O 70
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The array is of structs? Or it's of strings in the format LETTER SPACE INTEGER?

Comment: You edited the question, but still it's not clear what do you mean with "a char and int as a combination".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to *remove multiple occurrences* but to sum the values associated to each character.

The key in the couples is just a character so the possible values are limited and it is possible to use them as the index in an array containing the sum of the associated values and an other one indicating if the character was used. In case the numbers associated to a character are always positive it is possible to have only one array initializing the count to -1.

After by definition iterating on the consecutive indexes to write the counts produces them sorted on the character.

For instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
  int n, i;
  int count[1 << CHAR_BIT] = { 0 };
  char used[1 << CHAR_BIT] = { 0 };

  /* read inputs */
  puts("enter number of couples:");
  if ((scanf("%d", &n) != 1) || (n <= 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid number");
    return -1;
  }

  puts("enter couples");
  for (i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    unsigned char c;
    int v;

    if (scanf(" %c %d", &c, &v) != 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid couple");
      return -1;
    }
    used[c] = 1;
    count[c] += v;
  }

  /* write result */
  puts("result :");
  for (i = 0; i != (1 << CHAR_BIT); ++i) {
    if (used[i])
      printf("%c %d\n", (char) i, count[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Some remarks :

- I do not suppose how many bits there are in a char, I use `CHAR_BIT`.
- In the format `" %c %d"` the space before `%c` allows to bypass the spaces/newline
- I force the character *c* to be *unsigned* because I use it as an index and do not want to take the risk to have a negative index
- *of course* when I do a *scanf* I check it success

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra -Wall c.c
/tmp % ./a.out
enter number of couples:
5
enter couples
M 25 A 50 
      O 70 A 45 L 100
result :
A 95
L 100
M 25
O 70
```

Comment: Can you please change the memory allocation to dynamic using malloc for the int and char?

Comment: @Kushal can be `int * count = calloc(1 << CHAR_BIT, sizeof(int)); char * used = calloc(1 << CHAR_BIT, 1);` I use _calloc_ to also set to 0. Why you do not do by yourself ? What is the problem ?

Comment: I do not have much idea regarding dynamic memory allocation.